# razor MVC foreach with @using (html.beginform())

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I need to create a form with a question and a text box to allow user enter their answer and send for validation. It seems `@using (Html.BeginForm())` is not valid with `@foreach`. Below is the code but I am not sure if this is the correct way. Can someone point me in the right direction please? Or how can I use `@using (Html.BeginForm())` for the scenario.

```
@model PairingTest.Web.Models.QuestionnaireViewModel

<html>
<head>
    <title>@Model.QuestionnaireTitle</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="~/Questionnaire/ProcessData" method="post">

        @foreach (var s in Model.QuestionsText) {

            <text> Question :</text>@s <br />
            @Html.Label("Ans");<br />
            @Html.TextBox("Ans");<br /> 

        }

        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form> 
</body>
```

Comment: Can you show the code with your razor form and not the html form

Comment: Btw my guess on your problem is you had the @ symbol infront of both the using (HTML.beginform())  and the foreach. You actually don't need the @ infront of the for each when its surrounded in the using (HTML.beginform()) becuase its in the razor scope and that will throw and error.

Comment: What is the controller method signature you posting back to and what is the model?  All you doing here is posting pack an array of `Ans` values which is not binding to anything and would be meaningless

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@using(Html.BeginForm())
{
  for(int i=0;i< Model.QuestionsText.Count;i++)
  {
     <text> Question :</text>@s <br />
     @Html.Label("Ans");<br />
     @Html.TextBoxFor(m => Model.QuestionsText[i].Ans);
  }
}
```

This will post collection of QuestionsText, let me know if you any query.

Answer (score -2):

You need to use IEnumerable with models